# DbReader object no result, stuck condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, informix

I am confused about passing multiple result set (returned from a Select Query) to my View. In current implementation:

1. The Controller has a function that reads all Query result in List of Objects Agent  Type.
2. The Query returned result i.e. List is passed in return statement to View.

> **Problem:**
>
> The query is good I confirmed it, but the data is not coming into the
>   DbReader. There is no error the program just stops and nothing is
>   returned. Last statement to print in Logs is "In Do-While Read Condition". Am I doing something wrong in my code ? Also, can I pass DbReader object directly in Return statement to my View ?

```
try
{
    logger.AddLog("Connection Set to CreateCommand");
    cmd = DBConnection.CreateCommand();
    logger.AddLog("Set cmd to Qeueue Stats");
    cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
    logger.AddLog("DbReader cmd Setting");
    DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //  OdbcDat dt = new DataTable();//
    //  dt = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    logger.AddLog("DB Reader Command Complete");
    logger.AddLog("DB Reader.Read() Going To Call");
    DbReader.Read();
    logger.AddLog("DB Reader.Read() Completed Call");
    dataComing = true;
    logger.AddLog("DrReader is:"+ Reader.FieldCount);

    logger.AddLog("Testing Data:" + Reader.GetString(2));

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    dataComing = false;
    logger.AddLog("ERROR while intiating DB Connection in Show Controller,error is:" + e.ToString());
    return View();
}
do
{
     //agents is a LIST of Objects type Agent class
     logger.AddLog("In Do-While Read Condition");
     logger.AddLog("AgentName = " + DbReader["AgentName"].ToString());
     agents.Add(new Agent {
            name = DbReader["AgentName"].ToString(),
            state = DbReader["State"].ToString(),
            systemtime = Convert.ToDateTime(DbReader["SystemTime"].ToString()),
            statechange = Convert.ToDateTime(DbReader["statechange"].ToString()),
     });
} while (DbReader.Read());

return Json(agents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Did you call DbReader.Read before entering the do..while loop?

Comment: `using (var reader = query.ExecuteReader()) { while (reader.Read()) {...} }`

Comment: Dmitri@ I used the same as well using Implicit typed variable. But still no result. What am I missing ?

Comment: You have not tested if the first DbReader.Read returns true.

Comment: while (DbReader.Read());  This will check automatically for that isn't it so ? Also there is Data in Table so Query definitely will return

Comment: I used while loop at first. Then shifted to do while - Hit and Trial

Comment: When the code reaches the while you have already tried to use the DbReader without checking if there is a current record. However what is the log result for _logger.AddLog("Testing Data:" + Reader.GetString(2));_ and the previous call to FieldCount?

Comment: ERROR while intiating DB Connection in Show Controller,error is:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.Controllers.DriverController.GetData()

Comment: logger.AddLog("DB Reader.Read() Going To Call");    This is the last command to run after it no Logs just the above commented error

Comment: Can you show the value of the variable _myQuery_?

Comment: It looks like when you use your reader it is out of scope. Place the do or while before the catch or move your reader variable outside the try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [NextResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) if you work in multiple result sets.

Check 'Retrieving Multiple Result Sets using NextResult' section out from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you truly have multiple result sets the above is correct. You don't call NextResult anywhere.